# On Debian Testing, apt-get install libsundials-dev insists on removing Cuda... why?

Tags: debian, apt-get

Pretty much like the title says...

When I want to install `sundials` (and friends), `apt-get` wants to remove `cuda`, `cuda drivers` and `cuda runtime`. This isn't the case if I just want to install, say, `libsundials-ida6`.

`apt-cache policy` on a few of the cuda pkgs shows there are only one of them.

Not a super biggy, but a couple software I use each want to either use the system version or bring in their private dependencies, and I don't want to waste space...

Thanks for any insight!

**Update: same problem with installing `petsc-dev`, which is a dependent.  Using `apt-get (r)depends`, or `aptitude --full-resolver`, doesn't shed light on it either.**

**Update 2:  Guess a similar question... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154977/why-is-apt-get-trying-to-remove-certain-packages-when-i-install-wine**

For example, here is my lengthy `apt-get` output:

```
X@X:~/$ sudo apt-get -s install libsundials-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cuda-cccl-12-0 cuda-command-line-tools-12-0 cuda-compiler-12-0 cuda-cudart-12-0 cuda-cudart-dev-12-0
  cuda-cuobjdump-12-0 cuda-cupti-12-0 cuda-cupti-dev-12-0 cuda-cuxxfilt-12-0 cuda-documentation-12-0
  cuda-driver-dev-12-0 cuda-gdb-12-0 cuda-libraries-12-0 cuda-libraries-dev-12-0 cuda-nsight-12-0
  cuda-nsight-compute-12-0 cuda-nsight-systems-12-0 cuda-nvcc-12-0 cuda-nvdisasm-12-0 cuda-nvml-dev-12-0
  cuda-nvprof-12-0 cuda-nvprune-12-0 cuda-nvrtc-12-0 cuda-nvrtc-dev-12-0 cuda-nvtx-12-0 cuda-nvvp-12-0
  cuda-opencl-12-0 cuda-opencl-dev-12-0 cuda-profiler-api-12-0 cuda-sanitizer-12-0 cuda-toolkit-12-0
  cuda-toolkit-12-0-config-common cuda-toolkit-12-config-common cuda-toolkit-config-common
  cuda-tools-12-0 cuda-visual-tools-12-0 gds-tools-12-0 libcublas-12-0 libcublas-dev-12-0 libcufft-12-0
  libcufft-dev-12-0 libcufile-12-0 libcufile-dev-12-0 libcurand-12-0 libcurand-dev-12-0 libcusolver-12-0
  libcusolver-dev-12-0 libcusparse-12-0 libcusparse-dev-12-0 libnpp-12-0 libnpp-dev-12-0
  libnvidia-allocator1 libnvidia-fbc1 libnvidia-opticalflow1 libnvjitlink-12-0 libnvjitlink-dev-12-0
  libnvjpeg-12-0 libnvjpeg-dev-12-0 libnvoptix1 libnvvm-samples-12-0 libtinfo5 libxnvctrl-dev
  nsight-compute-2022.4.1 nsight-systems-2022.4.2 nvidia-detect nvidia-xconfig
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-mathjax ksh ksh93u+m libbtf1 libcombblas1.16.0 libcxsparse3 libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev
  libfftw3-long3 libfftw3-mpi-dev libfftw3-mpi3 libfftw3-quad3 libgraphblas-dev libgraphblas7
  libhdf5-mpi-dev libhdf5-openmpi-103-1 libhdf5-openmpi-cpp-103-1 libhdf5-openmpi-dev
  libhdf5-openmpi-fortran-102 libhdf5-openmpi-hl-100 libhdf5-openmpi-hl-cpp-100
  libhdf5-openmpi-hl-fortran-100 libhypre-2.26.0 libhypre-dev libjs-mathjax libklu1 libldl2 libmongoose2
  libmumps-5.5 libmumps-dev libmumps-headers-dev libpetsc-real-dev libpetsc-real3.18
  libpetsc-real3.18-dev libpetsc3.18-dev-common libpetsc3.18-dev-examples libptscotch-7.0 libptscotch-dev
  librbio2 libscalapack-mpi-dev libscalapack-openmpi-dev libscalapack-openmpi2.2 libsliplu1 libspqr2
  libsuitesparse-dev libsundials-arkode5 libsundials-cvode6 libsundials-cvodes6 libsundials-ida6
  libsundials-idas5 libsundials-kinsol6 libsundials-nvecparallel-hypre6 libsundials-nvecparallel-mpi6
  libsundials-nvecparallel-openmp6 libsundials-nvecparallel-petsc6 libsundials-nvecparallel-pthread6
  libsundials-nvecserial6 libsundials-sunlinsol3 libsundials-sunmatrix4 libsuperlu-dist-dev
  libsuperlu-dist8 libtrilinos-amesos-13.2 libtrilinos-aztecoo-13.2 libtrilinos-aztecoo-dev
  libtrilinos-epetra-13.2 libtrilinos-epetraext-13.2 libtrilinos-galeri-13.2 libtrilinos-ifpack-13.2
  libtrilinos-kokkos-13.2 libtrilinos-ml-13.2 libtrilinos-ml-dev libtrilinos-teuchos-13.2
  libtrilinos-trilinosss-13.2 libtrilinos-trilinosss-dev libtrilinos-triutils-13.2
  libtrilinos-zoltan-13.2 libtrilinos-zoltan-dev libyaml-dev ocl-icd-libopencl1 ocl-icd-opencl-dev
  opencl-c-headers opencl-clhpp-headers petsc-dev trilinos-dev valgrind valgrind-dbg valgrind-mpi
Suggested packages:
  libfftw3-doc libhdf5-doc fonts-mathjax-extras fonts-stix libjs-mathjax-doc libpetsc-real3.18-dbg
  petsc3.18-doc libluminate-dev scalapack-doc trilinos-doc libyaml-doc opencl-clhpp-headers-doc
  kcachegrind alleyoop valkyrie
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cuda cuda-12-0 cuda-demo-suite-12-0 cuda-drivers cuda-drivers-525 cuda-runtime-12-0 nvidia-libopencl1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-mathjax ksh ksh93u+m libbtf1 libcombblas1.16.0 libcxsparse3 libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev
  libfftw3-long3 libfftw3-mpi-dev libfftw3-mpi3 libfftw3-quad3 libgraphblas-dev libgraphblas7
  libhdf5-mpi-dev libhdf5-openmpi-103-1 libhdf5-openmpi-cpp-103-1 libhdf5-openmpi-dev
  libhdf5-openmpi-fortran-102 libhdf5-openmpi-hl-100 libhdf5-openmpi-hl-cpp-100
  libhdf5-openmpi-hl-fortran-100 libhypre-2.26.0 libhypre-dev libjs-mathjax libklu1 libldl2 libmongoose2
  libmumps-5.5 libmumps-dev libmumps-headers-dev libpetsc-real-dev libpetsc-real3.18
  libpetsc-real3.18-dev libpetsc3.18-dev-common libpetsc3.18-dev-examples libptscotch-7.0 libptscotch-dev
  librbio2 libscalapack-mpi-dev libscalapack-openmpi-dev libscalapack-openmpi2.2 libsliplu1 libspqr2
  libsuitesparse-dev libsundials-arkode5 libsundials-cvode6 libsundials-cvodes6 libsundials-dev
  libsundials-ida6 libsundials-idas5 libsundials-kinsol6 libsundials-nvecparallel-hypre6
  libsundials-nvecparallel-mpi6 libsundials-nvecparallel-openmp6 libsundials-nvecparallel-petsc6
  libsundials-nvecparallel-pthread6 libsundials-nvecserial6 libsundials-sunlinsol3 libsundials-sunmatrix4
  libsuperlu-dist-dev libsuperlu-dist8 libtrilinos-amesos-13.2 libtrilinos-aztecoo-13.2
  libtrilinos-aztecoo-dev libtrilinos-epetra-13.2 libtrilinos-epetraext-13.2 libtrilinos-galeri-13.2
  libtrilinos-ifpack-13.2 libtrilinos-kokkos-13.2 libtrilinos-ml-13.2 libtrilinos-ml-dev
  libtrilinos-teuchos-13.2 libtrilinos-trilinosss-13.2 libtrilinos-trilinosss-dev
  libtrilinos-triutils-13.2 libtrilinos-zoltan-13.2 libtrilinos-zoltan-dev libyaml-dev ocl-icd-libopencl1
  ocl-icd-opencl-dev opencl-c-headers opencl-clhpp-headers petsc-dev trilinos-dev valgrind valgrind-dbg
  valgrind-mpi
0 upgraded, 88 newly installed, 7 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Remv cuda [12.0.1-1]
Remv cuda-12-0 [12.0.1-1]
Remv cuda-demo-suite-12-0 [12.0.140-1]
Remv cuda-runtime-12-0 [12.0.1-1]
Remv cuda-drivers [525.85.12-1]
Remv cuda-drivers-525 [525.85.12-1]
Remv nvidia-libopencl1 [525.85.12-1] [libhwloc-plugins:amd64 nvidia-opencl-icd:amd64 libavutil56:amd64 libavutil57:amd64 libavfilter8:amd64 ]
Inst ocl-icd-libopencl1 (2.3.1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst fonts-mathjax (2.7.9+dfsg-1 Debian:testing [all])
Inst ksh93u+m (1.0.4-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst ksh (20230128 Debian:testing [all])
Inst libbtf1 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libcombblas1.16.0 (1.6.2-8 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libcxsparse3 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libfftw3-long3 (3.3.10-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libfftw3-quad3 (3.3.10-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libfftw3-bin (3.3.10-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libfftw3-dev (3.3.10-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libfftw3-mpi3 (3.3.10-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libfftw3-mpi-dev (3.3.10-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libgraphblas7 (7.4.0+dfsg-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libgraphblas-dev (7.4.0+dfsg-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libhdf5-openmpi-103-1 (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libhdf5-openmpi-fortran-102 (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libhdf5-openmpi-hl-100 (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libhdf5-openmpi-hl-fortran-100 (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libhdf5-openmpi-cpp-103-1 (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libhdf5-openmpi-hl-cpp-100 (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libhdf5-openmpi-dev (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libhdf5-mpi-dev (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libptscotch-7.0 (7.0.2-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsuperlu-dist8 (8.1.2+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libhypre-2.26.0 (2.26.0-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libhypre-dev (2.26.0-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libjs-mathjax (2.7.9+dfsg-1 Debian:testing [all])
Inst libklu1 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libldl2 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libmongoose2 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libscalapack-openmpi2.2 (2.2.1-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libmumps-5.5 (5.5.1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libmumps-headers-dev (5.5.1-1 Debian:testing [all])
Inst libscalapack-openmpi-dev (2.2.1-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libscalapack-mpi-dev (2.2.1-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libmumps-dev (5.5.1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libspqr2 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-kokkos-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-teuchos-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-epetra-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-triutils-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-epetraext-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-trilinosss-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-amesos-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-aztecoo-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-galeri-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-ifpack-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-zoltan-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-ml-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libpetsc-real3.18 (3.18.3+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst librbio2 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsliplu1 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsuitesparse-dev (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libptscotch-dev (7.0.2-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst opencl-c-headers (3.0~2022.09.30-1 Debian:testing [all])
Inst opencl-clhpp-headers (3.0~2022.09.30-1 Debian:testing [all])
Inst ocl-icd-opencl-dev (2.3.1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsuperlu-dist-dev (8.1.2+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libyaml-dev (0.2.5-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libpetsc3.18-dev-common (3.18.3+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [all])
Inst trilinos-dev (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-aztecoo-dev (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-trilinosss-dev (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-ml-dev (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libtrilinos-zoltan-dev (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst valgrind (1:3.19.0-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst valgrind-mpi (1:3.19.0-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libpetsc-real3.18-dev (3.18.3+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libpetsc-real-dev (3.18.3+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [all])
Inst libpetsc3.18-dev-examples (3.18.3+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [all])
Inst libsundials-arkode5 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsundials-cvode6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsundials-cvodes6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsundials-ida6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsundials-idas5 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsundials-kinsol6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsundials-nvecserial6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsundials-nvecparallel-mpi6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsundials-nvecparallel-pthread6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsundials-nvecparallel-openmp6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsundials-nvecparallel-hypre6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsundials-nvecparallel-petsc6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsundials-sunmatrix4 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst libsundials-sunlinsol3 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst petsc-dev (3.18.3+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [all])
Inst libsundials-dev (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Inst valgrind-dbg (1:3.19.0-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf ocl-icd-libopencl1 (2.3.1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf fonts-mathjax (2.7.9+dfsg-1 Debian:testing [all])
Conf ksh93u+m (1.0.4-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf ksh (20230128 Debian:testing [all])
Conf libbtf1 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libcombblas1.16.0 (1.6.2-8 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libcxsparse3 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libfftw3-long3 (3.3.10-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libfftw3-quad3 (3.3.10-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libfftw3-bin (3.3.10-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libfftw3-dev (3.3.10-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libfftw3-mpi3 (3.3.10-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libfftw3-mpi-dev (3.3.10-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libgraphblas7 (7.4.0+dfsg-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libgraphblas-dev (7.4.0+dfsg-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libhdf5-openmpi-103-1 (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libhdf5-openmpi-fortran-102 (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libhdf5-openmpi-hl-100 (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libhdf5-openmpi-hl-fortran-100 (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libhdf5-openmpi-cpp-103-1 (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libhdf5-openmpi-hl-cpp-100 (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libhdf5-openmpi-dev (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libhdf5-mpi-dev (1.10.8+repack1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libptscotch-7.0 (7.0.2-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsuperlu-dist8 (8.1.2+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libhypre-2.26.0 (2.26.0-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libhypre-dev (2.26.0-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libjs-mathjax (2.7.9+dfsg-1 Debian:testing [all])
Conf libklu1 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libldl2 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libmongoose2 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libscalapack-openmpi2.2 (2.2.1-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libmumps-5.5 (5.5.1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libmumps-headers-dev (5.5.1-1 Debian:testing [all])
Conf libscalapack-openmpi-dev (2.2.1-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libscalapack-mpi-dev (2.2.1-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libmumps-dev (5.5.1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libspqr2 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-kokkos-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-teuchos-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-epetra-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-triutils-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-epetraext-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-trilinosss-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-amesos-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-aztecoo-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-galeri-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-ifpack-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-zoltan-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-ml-13.2 (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libpetsc-real3.18 (3.18.3+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf librbio2 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsliplu1 (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsuitesparse-dev (1:5.12.0+dfsg-2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libptscotch-dev (7.0.2-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf opencl-c-headers (3.0~2022.09.30-1 Debian:testing [all])
Conf opencl-clhpp-headers (3.0~2022.09.30-1 Debian:testing [all])
Conf ocl-icd-opencl-dev (2.3.1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsuperlu-dist-dev (8.1.2+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libyaml-dev (0.2.5-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libpetsc3.18-dev-common (3.18.3+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [all])
Conf trilinos-dev (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-aztecoo-dev (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-trilinosss-dev (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-ml-dev (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libtrilinos-zoltan-dev (13.2.0-3+b2 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf valgrind (1:3.19.0-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf valgrind-mpi (1:3.19.0-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libpetsc-real3.18-dev (3.18.3+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libpetsc-real-dev (3.18.3+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [all])
Conf libpetsc3.18-dev-examples (3.18.3+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [all])
Conf libsundials-arkode5 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsundials-cvode6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsundials-cvodes6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsundials-ida6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsundials-idas5 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsundials-kinsol6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsundials-nvecserial6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsundials-nvecparallel-mpi6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsundials-nvecparallel-pthread6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsundials-nvecparallel-openmp6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsundials-nvecparallel-hypre6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsundials-nvecparallel-petsc6 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsundials-sunmatrix4 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf libsundials-sunlinsol3 (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf petsc-dev (3.18.3+dfsg1-1 Debian:testing [all])
Conf libsundials-dev (6.4.1+dfsg1-3 Debian:testing [amd64])
Conf valgrind-dbg (1:3.19.0-1 Debian:testing [amd64])
```